Is the separability of $m+1>d$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ preserved if we use a weight vector orthogonal to one of the vectors?
$\def\bx{\mathbf{x}}$
$\def\bw{\mathbf{w}}$
$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
Vectors $\bx_1,\ldots, \bx_{m},\bx_{m+1} \in \R^d$ ($m>d$) are linearly separable by a hyperplane $\bw \cdot \bx =0$:
\begin{align}
\bw \cdot \bx_i &> 0  &&i=1,\ldots,n \\
\bw \cdot \bx_j &< 0  && j=n+1,\ldots,m+1.
\end{align}
Any subset with $k$ vectors where $k\leq d$ is linearly separable.
Does there exist a vector $\bw'$ such that
\begin{align}
\bw' \cdot \bx_i &> 0  &&i=1,\ldots,n \\
\bw' \cdot \bx_j &< 0  && j=n+1,\ldots,m \\
\bw' \cdot \bx_{m+1} &= 0 &&?
\end{align}

Just a simple counter-example unless I'm misunderstanding, what if $\bf{x}_{m+1} = \lambda\bf{x}_{j}$ for some real $\lambda$ and $j$ between $1$ and $m$ ($\lambda$ positive if $j>n$, else negative), then these conditions can't work?
